# Is this a quadratic programming problem?

Tags: quadratic-programming

I have $N$ unknown 2D points ${\bf x} = (x,y)$ and I want to minimize:

$f({\bf x}) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(||x_{i+1} - x_i||_2 - c_i)^2}$

where c are $N-1$ known scalars. What is the simplest form that I can use to solve this? I was thinking to try to express it as a quadratic programming problem by solving for the homogeneous coordinates of the points, and in the end divide by the $3^{rd}$ coordinate:

${\bf x}^TQ{\bf x} + {\bf c}^T{\bf x}$

where ${\bf x}$ is now a $3N\times 1$ vector. The reason the minimization expands to quadratic polynomials with two variables, in the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$, where $b=0$.

Would this work? If yes, is there any tricky bit that I should be aware of?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, you are choosing an order for the $x_i$ so that the sum is minimised?

Comment: what do you mean by order? I don't know either $x_i$ or $y_i$ $\forall i \in [1,N]$. I want to calculate them so they minimize the mean squared error of the length differences to some known lengths $c_i$ (ok correcting this bit, my bad)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand it, but the equation to make the cost functional zero would be $\|x_{i+1}-x_{i}\|=c_{i}\ \forall i\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$...Now you can think about if it is possible to choose the $x_{i}$ such that the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: It's as you say, but I actually want to solve it in a least-squares sense, as in my case there is no solution which makes the functional zero.

Comment: Oh the question has changed, before the $c_i$ were just floating around without a square.  It's interesting, I am currently working on the continuous version of this problem

Comment: If you change your functional to $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left(\|x_{i+1}-x_{i}\|^{2}_{2}-c_{i}^{2}\right)$ it is certainly quadratic...and should do what you want to...